# How to install fuse

Tags: python, fuse

I am trying to install fuse. FUSE is installed successfully, however, when I try to import it-it generates an error

I am using Python 2.7. And I want to use FUSE with leveldb. For leveldb, I followed this tutorial which asked me to create a virtual env. I installed FUSE within virtual env and outside of it but problem persists.

https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

```
from fuse import FUSE, FuseOSError, Operations
```

This is the error that I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 10, in <module>
    from fuse import FUSE, FuseOSError, Operations
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fuse'
```

I used sudo apt-get install fuse and this is the output

```
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
fuse is already the newest version (2.9.4-1ubuntu3.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 508 not upgraded.
```

Comment: You need to install it for python, not your system.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @jhpratt

Comment: Use `pip`, not `apt`. So something along the lines of `pip install fuse`, or whatever the relevant library is called.

Comment: @jhpratt Still not working

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the package you would like to use. There are many bindings and implementations in different languages, but I will name 2:

[python-fuse](https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse), which is working with FUSE < version 3 and [pyfuse3](https://github.com/libfuse/pyfuse3), which is working for FUSE 3.
Right now the linux kernel delivers FUSE in version 2. So I would suggest to use the first library.

For installation I forward you to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/fuse-python/). There you find additional information about the package and the installation command.

As you work with virtualenv, I would suggest to read [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) article to familiarize with it. There you find more information about simple operations with virtual envs.

Did that help you? Feel free to ask, if you don't understand my explanation.